# Angular FormControl objects are able to accept input values of any type, or are restricted to typescript primitive types?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am using FormControl objects in a FormGroup to create a reactive form in Angular. There is no problem when I pass primitive arguments as a value of an HTML input select control. However, when I pass an object of a self-defined class, the value in the FormControl is reduced to [object Object].

The system I am working in includes:
Angular CLI: 7.1.4; 
Node: 10.15.0; 
Angular: 7.1.4; 
rxjs      6.3.3; 
typescript 3.1.6; 
webpack  4.23.1; 
Linux rdz1 4.15.0-43-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 6 14:45:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-header-notes',
    templateUrl: './header-notes.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./header-notes.component.css']
})

export class HeaderNotesComponent implements OnInit {
    ndcForm = new FormGroup({
        noteType: new FormControl(''),
        noteDate: new FormControl(''),
        noteFor: new FormControl(''),
        noteTo: new FormControl(''),
        noteDetail: new FormControl(''),
        noteDetailVal: new FormControl(''),
        noteChkRefInvoice: new FormControl('')
    });

    ngOnInit() { this.onChanges(); }

    onChanges(): void{
        this.ndcForm.valueChanges
        .subscribe( val => console.log(val))
    }
}
```

The console shows something like:
{noteType: "credit", noteDate: "2019-01-01", noteTo: [object Object], ... }

I am passing an object {param1: val1, parm2: val2} to "noteTo" , so I would expect to watch this value in the console, however it is showing [object Object]. It looks like if the object has been stringified.

Comment: May you can try to pass the object via an angular pipe and log it afterwards.

Comment: I am passing an object {param1: val1, parm2: val2} to "noteTo"  can you share the part of code when you are passing the object to "noteTo"?

Comment: Cloud you paste your self-defined class code into question?

Comment: `<select formControlName="noteTo">
            <option *ngFor="let cargoAg of dfCargoAgs" [value]="cargoAg">{{cargoAg.nombre}}</option>
          </select>`  where dfCargoAgs is an array of objects of a predefined class.

Comment: The predefined class is `export class Aliado {
  alias: string;
  ciudad: string;
  direccion: string;
  id_aliado: number;
  id_pais: number;
  id_tipoaliado: number;
  identidad: string;
  nombre: string;
  pais: string;
  telefono: string;
  tiempago: number;
  tipo: string;
  }
`

Comment: What are param1 and param2 used for in select? Record the selected value?

Comment: This because the value attribute of html <option> tag accepts only text values, so the object is converted to string automatically, and the rappresentation of any js object to string is [object Object]  [https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp. In this case you have to implement custom select control using Angular interface ControlValueAccessor. This article can help you: https://blog.angularindepth.com/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms-93b9eee9ee83

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the answer. In the form, instead of using:

```
<option *ngFor="let cargoAg of dfCargoAgs" [value]="cargoAg">{{cargoAg.nombre}}</option>
```

I had to use:

```
<option *ngFor="let cargoAg of dfCargoAgs" [ngValue]="cargoAg">{{cargoAg.nombre}}</option>
```

So [value] accepts only primitive types, but [ngValue] can accept objects of any class.
I hope this can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in assuming that the object is being "stringified".

You can override `toString()` on your custom type in order to get the desired output in the form in HTML.

However, if you want to be able to convert back from the form to get the value as an object of that custom type then you will have to create a method for doing so, which can be kind of annoying.

Another solution would be to break out the properties of your custom type into a nested `FormGroup` inside of your `ndcForm` `FormGroup`, like so:

```ts
ndcForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    noteType: new FormControl(''),
    noteDate: new FormControl(''),
    noteFor: new FormControl(''),
    noteTo: new FormGroup({
        any: new FormControl(''),
        custom: new FormControl(''),
        property: new FormControl('')
    }),
    noteDetail: new FormControl(''),
    noteDetailVal: new FormControl(''),
    noteChkRefInvoice: new FormControl('')
});
```

You will have to take some care to extract each value from the object to place it into the form, and vice versa.

Go to the Angular docs for info on [nesting `FormGroup` instances](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-nested-form-groups).

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to override toString() in my class, but the console kept showing [object Object]. The nested Form alternative is not applicable since the data is loaded from a single select tag. I think the FormControl class is designed to accept only primitive types, so it will be necessary to write a function to restore the objects from the respective formControl value.